# flash xml slideshow

Tags: xml, flash, slideshow, image-gallery

i'm doing a xml slideshow in flash and for that i have this slideshow (i've chose this because of the effects on images):

http://activeden.net/item/xml-slideshow-with-ken-burns-effect/32354

So this is what i've been looking for but now i need to fill the browser's screen... On this one, the size of the stage is determined by the value we put on the xml file, so i can't put there "100%"... i already tryied to open the fla and put the values directly but with no success.

Can anyone tell me how to change this or at least let me know if exists another tutorial or an already made plugin that do the same thing?

i'm trying to do something like this
http://www.salsajeans.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two parts to this, one is the fla/swf and the other is how the swf is presented.

you need to enable this 100% scaling for the browser, usually using swfobject (you can use this tool to generate the necessary code for that http://learnswfobject.com/generator/)

The trick to this kind of scaling is to align the stage to the top-left corner, and no scaling.

use an event listener to listen for changes in dimensions, and then scale the images dynamically according to the stage size.

here is an example without the listener for AS2
http://www.flashnutz.com/2009/08/scaling-a-dynamic-background-image-in-proportion-using-flash/